# GOBIN not set: cannot run go install

Tags: go

I am trying to install my custom package for my main.go file. However, when I ran

```
go install custom.go
```

I got this error

```
go install: no install location for .go files listed on command line (GOBIN not set)
```

How do I set GOBIN?

Comment: BTW: This is a *completely* wrong way to install a package. This will never work. `go install` installs **packages** not individual files. Please read all of http://golang.org/cmd/go/ and see how to set up your files.

Comment: I think you're looking for go build.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that it's completely wrong. When GOBIN is set, there are two distinct behaviours: When using go build <gofile.go>, the executable is created in the same folder. When using go install <gofile.go> the executable is created in GOBIN.

Comment: FWIW - the default docs to get started recommend that you do exactly this. https://golang.org/doc/install

Comment: @Volker 'go install' docs says
`For more about specifying packages, see 'go help packages'.`

'go help packages' near end says:

`As a special case, if the package list is a list of .go files from a
single directory, the command is applied to a single synthesized
package made up of exactly those files, ignoring any build constraints
in those files and ignoring any other files in the directory.`

So 'go install' is also for .go files. Problem is inconsistency, in case of package name provided GOBIN is not required while in case .go file is being installed GOBIN is being required.

Comment: @StevoSlavić that behavior was added a few releases ago. It is useful for specific usecases. The rule itself is still valid. The go tool works on packages, not on files.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Update 2020: since Go 1.11 and the [introduction of Go modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules), `GOPATH` is not needed anymore per project, and [defaults to `~/go`](https://rakyll.org/default-gopath/) for global tools/project you would `go get`.

[Go 1.16 (Q1 2020)](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23439#issuecomment-582483567) should default [`GOBIN` to  `GOPATH[0]/bin`](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23439#issuecomment-432812672).

But for now, for any project using modules, you would not have an error message like "`go install: no install location ...`" anymore.

---

Original answer 2014:

Check your `GOPATH` variable.
Make sure:

> - your sources are under `GOPATH/src`

- you have a `bin` folder within your GOPATH folder.

See [GOPATH environment variable](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable) (where 'DIR' is a `GOPATH` folder):

> The `bin` directory holds compiled commands.
> Each command is named for its source directory, but only the final element, not the entire path. That is, the command with source in `DIR/src/foo/quux` is installed into `DIR/bin/quux`, not `DIR/bin/foo/quux`. The "`foo/`" prefix is stripped so that you can add `DIR/bin` to your `PATH` to get at the installed commands.

> If the `GOBIN` environment variable is set, commands are installed to the directory it names instead of `DIR/bin`. `GOBIN` must be an absolute path.

---

For instance, [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/J5NP0Y6nnYE) illustrates what happen in the case where a go build is done outside of `GOPATH/src`:

> Looks like your `GOPATH` is set to `~/go` but you ran the `go install` command on `~/dev/go`

See [Go Build](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/)

> The Go path is a list of directory trees containing Go source code. It is consulted to resolve imports that cannot be found in the standard Go tree.

If you have done `go build`, you can also try a `go install` (no `custom.go`): you want to install the package, not a single file.

Comment: do you mean this? I did echo $PATH and got this: /Users/apple/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin

Answer (score 87):

I set the GOBIN path and that worked for me

```
export GOBIN=[WorkspacePath]/bin
```

Comment: yea, this is the correct answer. just create /bin in that GOPATH

Comment: After export path, I got the error `cannot install, GOBIN must be an absolute path` :(

Comment: @lee Did you use `..` or `~` in the path you specified? I got that error and just switched to an absolute path such as `/home/ben/bin/` or even `$HOME/bin/`. My full command was (in fishshell, go v1.11) `env GOBIN=$HOME/bin/ go install testfile.go`.

Answer (score 43):

As a beginner, I ran across this error when I was trying out various go commands (build, run, and install). In short, you cannot **go install** a *filename.go*. You can only install a package.

This was confusing, because I had learned that:

```
nate:~/work/src/dir $ go run hello/hello.go
hello, world.
```

works great. But I couldn't figure out why **install** wouldn't work:

```
nate:~/work/src/dir $ go install hello/hello.go 
go install: no install location for .go files listed on command line (GOBIN not set)
nate:~/work/src/dir $ go install hello
can't load package: package hello: cannot find package "hello" in any of:
    /opt/go/src/hello (from $GOROOT)
    /home/ubuntu/work/src/hello (from $GOPATH)
```

No matter what directory I was in:

```
nate:~/work/src/dir $ cd hello
nate:~/work/src/dir/hello $ go install hello.go 
go install: no install location for .go files listed on command line (GOBIN not set)
nate:~/work/src/dir/hello $ go install hello
can't load package: package hello: cannot find package "hello" in any of:
    /opt/go/src/hello (from $GOROOT)
    /home/ubuntu/work/src/hello (from $GOPATH)
```

This confusion is because [go run](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program) *only* works with Go source files (filenames that end in .go) and [go install](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_install_packages_and_dependencies) *only* accepts packages. Packages are named by their import paths or file system path. Thus:

```
nate:~/work/src/dir $ go install dir/hello
nate:~/work/src/dir $ go install ./hello/
nate:~/work/src/dir/hello $ go install .
```

all work great. The first refers to the package by import path, (given that  $GOPATH="/home/nate/work", the go tools look for source code in /home/nate/work/src), the others are interpreted as file system paths because of the leading periods.

See also the [GOPATH docs](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable).

Comment: this is the real solution IMO. `go install` works on directories and if you specify a particular go file, then it can cause this particular problem.

Answer (score 13):

Actually there are 2 different kinds of behavior.

```
go install <package>
```

this is documented in [Compile and install packages and dependencies](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_install_packages_and_dependencies)
You don't need GOBIN if you set GOPATH correctly.

```
go install <gofile>
```

this is not documented and you need GOBIN env variable in this mode.

Comment: `go install <gofile>` is documented, in `go help packages` to which `go install --help` refers to. Problem is that `go install` (in 1.9.2 and earlier) has inconsistent behaviour, in one case it requires and in other it does not require GOBIN to be explicitly set.

Answer (score 8):

For `*nix` system, look where `go` is installed, executing following command:

```
$ which go
```

which output let's say:

```
/usr/local/go/bin/go
```

then add following entries in `~/.bash_profile` or in `~/.zshrc`:

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=$GOROOT/src //your-go-workspace
export GOBIN=$GOROOT/bin //where go-generate-executable-binaries

PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH:$GOBIN

export PATH
```

**P.S:** Don't forget to source `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc`, as follows:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Do you really want development executables dropped into `/usr/local/go/bin`?

Answer (score 7):

As pervious answers pointed out, if your GOPATH env is correctly set to your workspace you don't need to set GOBIN env variable.

Please check your go environment variables by running $go env | grep -i "^GO" and look out for GOROOT and GOPATH to check if GOROOT is pointing to your GO source installation and GOPATH pointing to your workspace.

If everything is correct then navigate to the subdir where yourpkg.go resides then run $go build (without file name) first and $go install (again withour file name) second , if you don't see any error message on the screen your package is ready at your workspace/pkg/youros/../yourpackage.a

Answer (score 7):

On windows with cygwin it seems to be a good idea to set up GOBIN to $GOPATH/bin.

and remember to properly escape the windows file name separator:

```
$ echo $GOROOT
C:\Go\

carl@rainier ~/gocode/src/github.com/user/hello
$ echo $GOPATH
C:\cygwin64\home\carl\gocode

carl@rainier ~/gocode/src/github.com/user/hello
$ echo $GOBIN
C:\cygwin64\home\carl\gocode\bin
```

Answer (score 3):

For **WINDOWS** users

Open a command prompt (`Win` + `r` then type `cmd`) or a powershell window (`Win` + `x` then type `i`).

**Setting the GOPATH**

> **NOTE:** `GOPATH` **must not** be the same path as your Go installation.

```
go env -w GOPATH=c:\your-go-work
```

More details in the link below
https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH#windows

**Setting GOBIN**

```
go env -w GOBIN=C:\somewhere\else\bin
```

I recommend to check the code example provided by golang. It helped me a lot.
https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Command

Answer (score 3):

In Windows:

```
go env -w GOBIN=C:\Users\yourname\go\bin
```

Confirm with `go env` command that GOBIN is set, then `go install` command properly saves the executable properly in the bin directory.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding setting `GOBIN` variable version not requiring it and just relying on `GOPATH`:

1. `GOBIN` is required if we don't have a package, i.e. the file is directly in the `GOPATH` directory. This is likely when we are trying out the Go features as learners
2. For typical Go projects, the files are under the package directories. For these, `GOPATH` is good enough.
3. In other words, both the following solutions would work:
    a. Set `GOBIN` explicitly as $GOPATH/bin [only for learning purposes, can avoid]
    b. Create a subdirectory which would be your package name and move the .go files to it
4. I guess Go utilities should remove the above error and handle the scenario better - based on whether the argument is a directory or a source file

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same trouble(GOBIN need not be set separately), make sure you have the following

1. GOPATH is set (this also automatically sets GOBIN as $GOPATH/bin)
2. GOPATH has the following directories bin, pkg, src
3. custom.go is placed under src/<your_module>
4. then run `go install <your_module>`
5. you can find the check for the compiled binary(<your_module>) under bin folder

Answer (score 0):

From https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Environment_variables:

> GOBIN The directory where 'go install' will install a command.

and https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable:

> If the GOBIN environment variable is set, commands are installed to
>   the directory it names instead of DIR/bin. GOBIN must be an absolute
>   path.

and https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Modules__module_versions__and_more

> In module-aware mode, GOPATH no longer defines the meaning of imports
>   during a build, but it still stores downloaded dependencies (in
>   GOPATH/pkg/mod) and installed commands (in GOPATH/bin, unless GOBIN is
>   set).

So, it seems basically you can use GOBIN to temporarily or permanently override the default binary install location (ie `$GOPATH/bin`). I had success installing a 1-file go "script" using `env GOBIN=$HOME/bin/ go install testfile.go`. This was done using go v1.11.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`export GOROOT=""`

`export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin`