# How to Setup "Go" environment on Windows

Tags: windows, go, configuration, environment-variables

I'm trying to setup Go on my Windows machine,

I followed the instruction on this page https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces to launch hello.go and face some difficulties.

So, I downloaded and installed MSI file

Here is my Go version:
go version go1.12.4 windows/amd64

my go env:

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=F:\GoWorckspace\bin
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\Avetis\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=F:\GoWorckspace
set GOPROXY=
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=E:\Go
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=E:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\Avetis\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build714242958=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

GOPATH dir structure is:
-bin/
-pkg/
-src/
-hello/
hello.go

hello.go content:

```
package main

  import (
      "fmt"
  )

  func main() {
      fmt.Println("Hello World!")
  }
```

When I try `go install` I get this arror:

```
 F:\GoWorckspace\src\hello> go install hello.go
open C:\Users\Avetis\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build786217674\b001\exe\a.out.exe: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have tried different options, but all of them lead to the same error:

```
PS F:\GoWorckspace\src> go install .\hello\hello.go
open C:\Users\Avetis\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build220985190\b001\exe\a.out.exe: The system cannot find the file specified.
PS F:\GoWorckspace\src> go install .\hello
open C:\Users\Avetis\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build247169354\b001\exe\a.out.exe: The system cannot find the file specified.
PS F:\GoWorckspace\src> go install hello
open C:\Users\Avetis\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build365645162\b001\exe\a.out.exe: The system cannot find the file specified.
PS F:\GoWorckspace\src> go build .\hello\hello.go
open C:\Users\Avetis\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build274908638\b001\exe\a.out.exe: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

## Bounty Edit

A table like this would be helpfull

| go env | Default path | Alternative path | windows variable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GOPATH | ? | c:\dev\golang\ | %gopath% |
| GOBIN | ? | C:\dev\gobin\bin | ? |
| GOROOT | C:\Program Files\Go | C:\Program Files\Go | ? |
| GOMOD | ? | ? "" on my box | ? |
| GOWORK | ? | ? "" on my box | ? |

Also as a go beginner i was at first not aware that the source code must be placed in a subfolder `src` of `%gopath%` and that the directories `pkg` and `bin` are also required.

```
C:\cygwin64\bin>tree -L 1 %gopath%

c:\dev\golang
├── bin
├── pkg
└── src
```

Is a folder structure like the one needed for %gopath% (see above) mandatory for other go evn names?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61799130/819887) is written to set `GOBIN` to this `go env -w GOBIN=C:\Users\yourname\go\bin`.

- But is this also the case if my `GOPATH` / `%gopath%` points to `c:\dev\golang\`
- Must `GOBIN` be a subfolder below `GOPATH`?

Comment: Does your `C:\....\AppData\Local\Temp` folder exist? What if you do (from the `src` folder) `go install` without any arguments?

Comment: Did you create the `hello.go` file in the src folder directly or did you create the package path as it suggests here https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Command?

Comment: From within the `hello` directory, please show the output of `go build -x`

Comment: Just as a heads up, using go from WSL will remove most of these headaches.  Plus it will give you a nice environment to develop from that is separate from the rest of your system.

Answer (score 1):

This to me sounds like your **anti-virus** software (Windows Defender?) is deleting your executable.

See also https://go.dev/doc/faq#virus

When you call `go run` or `go install`, the program is built into your temp folder, then run (for `go run`) or copied to your `GOBIN` directory (for `go install`).

The problem is that as soon as the executable is built, it gets deleted by a buggy anti-virus software, thus the next step of running the executable or copying it to another folder, fails with the given error message.

To **solve** this, you can add your temp folder to the white-list of your anti-virus so it is not scanned. **Or** you can change the output directories (`GOBIN, GOCACHE, GOPATH, GOTMPDIR`) to folders that are already on your anti-virus software's white-list.

Comment: Running `go env GOBIN` returns `C:\dev\gobin\bin` . Running  `go install github.com/onsi/ginkgo/v2/ginkgo` fails with `cannot find package "github.com/onsi/ginkgo/v2/ginkgo" in any of:
        C:\Program Files\Go\src\github.com\onsi\ginkgo\v2\ginkgo (from $GOROOT)
        c:\dev\golang\src\github.com\onsi\ginkgo\v2\ginkgo (from $GOPATH)`
Running `go get github.com/onsi/ginkgo/v2/ginkgo` fails with the same error message as above: "cannot find package .../ginkgo in any of ..." Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

With the latest Go releases, the table is simple:

```
GOPATH=C:\path\to\Go\workspace (default: `%USERPROFILE%\go`)
GOROOT=C:\path\to\Go\installation
```

That's it.

- `GOROOT` references where [`go1.21.6.windows-amd64.zip`](https://go.dev/dl/go1.21.6.windows-amd64.zip) is extracted.
- `GOPATH` defines the root of your (global) workspace. But it is not where your project code is.

See also "[GOROOT and GOPATH](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/configuring-goroot-and-gopath.html#gopath)".

The most important step leading to a successful `go install` is the `go mod init example/user/hello`, done in your project folder (entirely different, and outside `%GOPATH%`. For instance, `c:\myproject`)

Create your `hello.go` in `c:\myproject`.
A `go install` will put a `hello.exe` in `%GOPATH%\bin`. If that one is in your `%PATH%`, you can start running `hello` immediately.
(not `go install .\hello\hello.go`, just `go install`)

Comment: Is there a reason to still set `GOROOT`? To my understanding doing so has been optional for several years now.

Comment: @Zyl I only set it when I have multiple versions of Go installed, and I want to use a specific one.